# How to get the name of a submitted form in Flask?

Tags: python, html, forms, post, flask

I'm building a website using Flask, and on one page I've got two forms. If there's a POST, I need to decide which form is being posted. I can of course deduct it from the fields that are present in `request.form`, but I would rather make it explicit by getting the name (defined by `<form name="my_form">`) of the form that is submitted. I tried several things, such as:

```
@app.route('/myforms', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def myForms():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print request.form.name
        print request.form.['name']
```

but unfortunately, nothing works. Does anybody know where I can get the name of the form submitted? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is no 'name of the form'. That information is not sent by the browser; the `name` attribute on `<form>` tags is meant to be used solely on the browser side (and deprecated to boot, use `id` instead).

You could *add* that information by using a hidden field, but the most common way to distinguish between forms posting to the same form handler is to give the submit button a name:

```html
<submit name="form1" value="Submit!"/>
```

and

```
if 'form1' in request.form:
```

but you could also use a `<input type="hidden">` field to include the means to distinguish between forms.

Comment: Thanks! That indeed solves my problem! I never knew that wasn't sent by the browser. One last question: what do you mean with "deprecated to boot"?

Comment: @kramer65: the `name` attribute has been deprecated in HTML 4. So not only isn't it useful for your use case, it is not even an attribute you should be using anymore.

Comment: Ah, awesome. I learned html in the nineties, after which I mainly worked in backend systems for years. So my html skills are a bit dated.. ;) Thanks a million!

Comment: Yeah, but how can you distinguish between two submit buttons when you have 2 submit buttons in Flask like so:  `form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info")`. Where can I specify the name attribute here?

Comment: @Nikos: if you have a `form.submit` attribute that is a submit field, then it is named `submit`. If you have multiple submit fields, they each have their own name *already*. The name for each comes from the attribute name you used when you created the fields: `fieldname = SubmitField(...)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're saying that the 'name' attribute is the variable fieldname? In other words in Flask forms your `fieldname = SubmitField(...)` is equal to, in HTML, `<input type='submit' name='fieldname' ...>`?

Comment: @Nikos: yes, exactly. WTForms always adds the bound fieldname to input fields as the `name` attribute, submit is no exception.