# Using webapp2, how can I get the value of a form's "name" attribute during a POST request?

Tags: html, forms, post, webapp2, webob

Code:

```
<form role="form" name="upload_type" action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I would like to inform my application to what type of form is being submitted by a user. I thought I could use the form's "name" attribute but can not figure out how to retrieve this value using `webapp2`.

Comment: Did you try validating your HTML? validate.w3c.org

Answer (score 0):

Read: [How to get the name of a submitted form in Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217779/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-submitted-form-in-flask)

For your python html forms I recommend [wtforms](/questions/tagged/wtforms) which will help you get everything about your form in webapp2 in one line of code [python](/questions/tagged/python). You can read the [manual](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/) about wtforms and what it can do. I recommend it for all your python forms.