# form input return None

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I want to take the input from my /user/conference uri.

Here is my controller:

```py
    @main.route('/user/conference', methods=["POST", "GET"])
    @login_required
    def user_search_conference():
        user = []
        conferences = []
        tags = []
        name = request.form.get('name')
        print(name)
        if name != "":
            user = db.session.query(UsersInfo).filter(
                UsersInfo.name == name).one()
            conferences = db.session.query(Conference).filter(
                Conference.creatoruser == user.authenticationid).all()
        else:
            conferences = db.session.query(Conference).all()
    
        return render_template('search_conference.html', conferences=conferences, len=len(conferences))
```

Here is my html form:

```html
    <div>
            <form method="POST" action="/user/conference">
                <div class="field">
                    <div class="control">
                        <input class="input is-large" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Conference Host">
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <button class="button is-block is-info is-large is-fullwidth">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

I added print for debugging and the name variable return None for that reason my databases cannot response. Why the form gives me None?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is here

```html
<input class="input is-large" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Conference Host">
```

This is missing the `id` attribute. So change this line to

```html
<input class="input is-large" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Conference Host">
```

And it should work.

The reason for this is that the attribute `name` is only used to identify the `input` field *within* the form filed, i.e. it is only on the browser side. But the `id` attribute is included in the request to the server. So you seem to have the same issue as [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217779/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-submitted-form-in-flask).